# How to display different titles in Data Gathering for Python?

Tags: python

When I execute the last code, the output I get is this:

```
['Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0',
 'Miss Jerry\xa0']
```

What did I do wrong?
From the previous practice I follow I able to display the output like this. I able to replicate the same coding as the previous one but it display all Miss Jerry instead.

```
['Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Book 6)',
 'Harry Potter And The Order Of The Phoenix',
 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (Book 2)',
 'Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (Book 3)',
 'Harry Potter Boxset Pb 1-5',
 'Unauthorized Harry Potter Book Seven News: "Half-Blood Prince" Analysis and Speculation',
 'The Harry Potter Collection: The First Six Spellbinding Adventures at Hogwarts',
 "The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide: Five Complete Novels and One Story (Deluxe Edition)",
 "The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
 "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, 25th Anniversary Edition"]
```

This is my code. I trying to extract the data from the IMBD website.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = './IMDB/IMDB movies.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False)

df.head(2)

id_all = df.imdb_title_id.tolist()[:10]
print(len(id_all))

id = id_all[0]
url = f'https://www.imdb.com/title/{id}'
filename = f'./IMDB/pages/{id}.html'
print(url)

import requests
response = requests.get(url)
with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(response.content)

with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
    response = fp.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'lxml')

titles = []
for id in id_all:
    filename: f'./IMDB/pages/{id}.html'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('h1').contents[0]
    titles.append(title)
```

Comment: Without your csv file we won't be able to help you. Here is a [great guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how you could improve your question so that we may be able to solve it.

Comment: I get the data from here: https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset

Comment: I use the IMDB movies.csv

Comment: Please don't just post links as a comment. This is confusing and will turn of a lot of people who might want to help you. Please follow the guide. Also [this particular guide will help you here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).